# How can I play my animation in reverse on hover in Adobe Animate?

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, timeline, tween

I am new to Adobe Animate (previously used Adobe Edge)

I have an entire animation (multiple layers) I would like to reverse play on hover (and stop reverse playing on hover out).

Can I use Adobe Flash tutorials exactly as they are for Adobe Animate? Maybe that's the reason I'm finding so few Adobe Animate tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use Adobe Flash tutorials exactly as they are for Adobe Animate?

Yes!! If you want something to react to mouse over/out then you use ActionScript 3 code (shortened to **AS3** for convenience).

- Draw a Stage-sized rectangle shape (filled but no outline colour) then right-click to convert the shape to `MovieClip` type.
- Select all animation frames from timeline, then cut & paste inside the new MClip (do this by double-clicking it to edit the MClip, and you are taken to timeline of the MClip itself where you then right-click and "paste frames"). Think of MClip as a "mini Stage".
- Now that your animation exists inside a MClip object, give the MClip an *instance name* by typing inside `instance` box of **Properties** panel. Your code references the object by its instance name.
- For code : Just make a new layer called "actions" or "code" and type your **AS3** code there. The layer exists on Stage. So on Stage you should have finally two layers (one for code & one for holding the MClip, all on frame 1 only).
- **note** : Code placed on frame *X* can only control other assets on frame *X* (can be different layers, but must exist on same frame number as code).

That's all I can say to beginner with setting things up to accept code to control a specific MClip to travel backwards or forwards.

Good luck with the tutorials.

Comment: Ah.... I think this is the step I was missing. Everything is not tucked away neatly in the movie clip layer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like this:

```
public function playInReverse(){
    your_mc.stop(); //your_mc is the movieclip/sprite you want to play in reverse
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, reverseEvent);
}

public function playNormally(){
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, reverseEvent);
    your_mc.play();
}

private function reverseEvent(evt:Event){
    //if your_mc is on the first frame, go to the last frame. Otherwise, go to previous frame.

    if(your_mc.currentFrame == first_frame){ //first_frame is the number or name of the first frame of the animation
        your_mc.gotoAndStop(last_frame); //last_frame is the number or name of the last frame of the animation

    }else{
        your_mc.prevFrame(); //go to the previous frame
    }
}
```

So when you want the movieclip/sprite to play in reverse you just call *playInReverse();* and when you want it to play normally you call *playNormally();* .

Additionally you can specify which movieclip/sprite to use by adding a parameter to *playNormally()* and *playInReverse()*. When using these functions instead, you can specify the object with a String as a parameter and supply it with the beginning and last frame numbers of the animation (ex: *playInReverse("your_mc_1", 1, 100);*  (or)  *playInReverse("your_mc_2", 14, 37);*  ):

```
private var reversing_mc:String;
private var first_frame:int;
private var last_frame:int;

public function playInReverse(the_mc:String, first_frame_number:int, last_frame_number:int){
    this[the_mc].stop();
    reversing_mc = the_mc;
    first_frame = first_frame_number;
    last_frame = last_frame_number;
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, reverseEvent);
}

public function playNormally(the_mc:String){
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, reverseEvent);
    this[the_mc].play();
}

private function reverseEvent(evt:Event){
    if(your_mc.currentFrame == first_frame){
        this[reversing_mc].gotoAndStop(last_frame);

    }else{
        this[reversing_mc].prevFrame();
    }
}
```